# Determine the type of distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with strictly increasing distribution function $F$. What type of distribution have the random variable $Y:=  -\ln(F(X))$

I can't think of many ideas to try to solve this, but we could try to find the cumulative distribution function of $Y$.

\begin{aligned}
    F_{Y}(y) &= P(Y \leq y) \\
     &= P(-\ln(F(X)) \leq y) \\
     &= 1-P(F(X) \leq e^{-y})
\end{aligned}

But of course, I don't see very clearly how to deduce the type of distribution from this; I can't think of anything else. Any hint/suggestion? any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next, you can write $\mathbb{P}(F_X(X) \le e^{-y}) = \mathbb{P}(X \le F_X^{-1}(e^{-y})) = F_X(F_X^{-1}(e^{-y})) = e^{-y}$ and finally $f_Y(y) = F_Y'(y) = e^{-y}$, so that $Y \sim \mathcal{Exp}(1)$ in fact.